# MongoDB find without index is fast certain values of a field

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection named "message" with 3.5 million documents. There are no indices on the collection except the _id index.

3.3 million of the documents have field "name" with value "peter".
200k of the documents have field "name" with value "john".

If I query db.message.find({name: "peter"}) it takes around 1 milliseconds.

If I query db.message.find({name: "john"}) it takes around 2 seconds.

My question is why is the one query really fast while the other slow?

Comment: how many executions of this query are you basing these figures on? - is this in a production environment? - are any end users reading data at the same time?

Comment: Its a db running on my laptop for testing so I am the only one reading data. I have run the queries multiple times and always there is a huge difference in performance. The performance increase seems to have to do with a large portion of the collection having the same value for a field.

Comment: @jimmy8ball I think it has to do with that it is much more likely to find documents with have name "peter". Because the cursor returns the first 20 docs in the shell it looks like one is query is faster then the other. When I exhaust the cursor both take a long time to complete. Hope this makes sense. Thanks for the help.